# Unable to get multiple sensor data

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I am playing with sensors to see what I can do with it so the first step is to get the sensor data. However there seems to be an issue with getting multiple sensors even any sensor other then the accelerometer. As that is the only data I am getting on my phone.

I have tried to run it with accelerometer off, but regardless the other sensore don't show their data.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

   //TODO: Database variables


    //Backend variables
    private SensorManager senSensorManager;
    private Sensor senAccelerometer, senLightsensor, senTemperatureSensor;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private float ACx, ACy, ACz;

    //UI variables
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private TextView LightResult, Debug, AcceleroResult;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senLightsensor = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
        senTemperatureSensor = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senLightsensor , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


        LightResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LightFound);
        AcceleroResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AcceleroResult);
        Debug = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Debug);

    }





    /**
     * using isRunning for each sensors ensures no unneeded updates are happening when app is turned off.
     */
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;

        myHandler.post(  new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             LightResult.setText(String.valueOf(lx));
             AcceleroResult.setText(String.valueOf(ACx));

         }
       }
       );


       if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT && isRunning) {

            float lx = event.values[0];
            LightResult.setText(String.valueOf(lx));


        }
      else  if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER && isRunning) {
            ACx = event.values[0];
            ACy = event.values[1];
            ACz = event.values[2];

           AcceleroResult.setText(String.valueOf(ACx));
       }
       else if(mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE && isRunning){

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    //Sensors dont run when app is not in foreground
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        isRunning = false;
    }
    //Turns sensors on when the app is in the foreground
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senTemperatureSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senLightsensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        isRunning = true;
    }
}
```